# How to pass in session variable to a form in play framework/scala to be stored in database

Tags: html, scala, playframework

Below is my form submission page. The `author` variable is what I want to be taken from the logged-in user, as it is a part of the data I need to be put in the database with the rest of these inputs. I want to know how I can get the username in this instance of the logged in user and pass it into the author field without the user needing to type it in himself.

```
@(itemForm: Form[models.SubmittedWork],user: models.users.User)

@import helper._

@main("Add submission",user){
    <p class="lead">Add a new submission</p>

    @form(action=routes.HomeController.addSubmissionSubmit(), 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role -> "form") {
        @* CSRF attack prevention *@
        @* This token, sent by the controller, will be used to authenticate the form submission *@
        @CSRF.formField

            @inputText(itemForm("name"), '_label -> "Name", 'class -> "form-control")
            @select(
                itemForm("Genre.id"),
                options(Genre.options),
                '_label -> "Genre", '_default -> "-- Choose a Genre --", 
                '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control"
            )
            @inputText(itemForm("text"), '_label -> "Text", 'class -> "form-control")

            @inputText(itemForm("id"), '_label -> "", 'hidden -> "hidden")
            @inputText(itemForm("author"),'_label -> "", 'hidden -> "hidden")

            <div class="actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Add/Update item" class="btn btn-primary">
                <a href="@routes.HomeController.works(0)">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                </a>
            </div>
    } @* end of form *@
} @* end of main *@
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wire this in through your controller.

```
  def myView(): Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit req =>
    val userId = req.session("user_id")
    val user = findUser(userId)
    Results.Ok(views.yourForm(itemForm, user))
  }
```

Then in your view:

```
<p class="username">${user.name}</p>
```

The `findUser` method or whatever will allow you to search for a `user` based on some kind of data within the request. `req.session(key)` will return `null` if the user is not logged in potentially so you may want an `Option[User]` instead.

The point is that you can pass through whatever variables to your form, and use `@{variable.field}` syntax to display whatever you like. The Twirl syntax allows you to do this, as well as for loops on collections to create a div for each element etc.

Have a quick read through the [**Twirl Syntax**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaTemplates), it should help you see all the examples of what it can do. To "get the data", it's generally preferable to put your logic in the controller, and pass it to your view.

Comment: I am able to display the username by typing in @{user.getUsername} thanks to you but I want it to be a part of the form, either displaying or not but not changeable which would link to the "Author" variable in my model

Comment: You do not need to input it on your form because you can access that `USER` on your controller and all you can do is display the username will be more easier and that will do the trick :)

Comment: from `Author` to `Option[Author]` field then just update the class value on the `Controller field`.